# Passing database config query value to native queries

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a configuration table where I configure select clause query string, I will get that string and  run a nativeQuery.

I am trying to achieve a functionality where I pass database returned values to the native MySQL/hibernate query using spring-boot, but having issues with Caused by org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

```
ConfigDTO reportsConfigDTO = reportsConfigRepository.getReportByCustomValue();
```

ConfigDTO had a field called SelectClause, when runs the query I am getting a SelectClause value from the database for example

```
SELECT * FROM users where  CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-27 19:06:02'
```

I am trying to pass this value to another query.

```
String query = reportsConfigDTO.getSelectClause();

UserDTO userDTO = userRoleRepository.getReportByCustom(query);
```

My native query in the repository is

```
@Query(value = ":query",  nativeQuery=true)
public UserDTO getReportByCustom(@Param("query") String query);
```

So basically I am passing this `SELECT * FROM users where  CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-27 19:06:02'` which is returned from the previous query to userRoleRepository.getReportByCustom

Am I doing something wrong? not sure if this is the correct approach,

I am getting below sql exception

> SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
>   2019-03-31 16:51:00.116 ERROR 33850 --- [   Batch] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SELECT * FROM users where  CREATE_DATE > \'2019-03-27 19:06:02\''' at line 1
>   Exception in thread "Reports" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

The query that you pass to the @Query should be a valid JPQL. What you are passing is a SQL query which JPA doesn't understand. Hence the error.

You should write something like this:

```
//Here UserDTO should be your Entity name. 
//Since date is a variable, you should receive it from the caller.
//Here `u` will automatically be an object of UserData pojo.
String QUERY = "SELECT u FROM UserDTO where CREATE_DATE > :date"

@Query(value = QUERY,  nativeQuery=true)
public UserDTO getReportByCustom(@Param("date") LocalDateTime date);
```

You can go through JPQL reference here -- https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html and https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpql/

**UPDATE**

You can put the Querys in a property file and read them from there like so:

```
//Some sql-query.properties file added to your classpath
sql.query.userQuery=SELECT u FROM UserDTO where CREATE_DATE > :date
```

and in your DAO layer read it like this:

```
@Value("${sql.query.userQuery}")
String QUERY;
```

Also if you are going to put the query in a database, you have to eventually write another query to fetch it. Also, you will be wasting extra read time on the query-reads.

Comment: Instead of writing these queries several places I am trying to pass the selectClause configured from the database where i can just change/modify query whenever I want. Do you have any solution for this specific requirement?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: The problem with your answer is you will need to re deploy the war/jar every time you change the query.  Also I don’t mind fetching the value. Like I said the question I am able to fetch the query successfully but when providing that query to another is getting error. I also tried like you suggested using select u from userDTO but there SQLgrammer exception

Comment: The value of query in -- `public UserDTO getReportByCustom(@Param("query") String query);` -- should be `"SELECT u FROM UserDTO where CREATE_DATE > '2019-03-27 19:06:02' "`. It should work.

Comment: Tried, same issue.2019-04-01 10:10:00.174  WARN 35144 --- [   ReportsBatch] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2019-04-01 10:10:00.175 ERROR 35144 --- [   ReportsBatch] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SELECT * FROM UserDTO u where  u.CREATE_DATE > \'2019-03-27 19:06:02\''' at line 1

Comment: You are using wrong query syntax `SELECT * FROM UserDTO u where u.CREATE_DATE > \'2019-03-27 19:06:02\'`. This is SQL syntax. You need to follow JPQL syntax like this -- `SELECT u FROM UserDTO where u.create_date > :date`. Notice that `create_date` should be the name of a feild in Entity class UserDTO.